# set lineheight in webbrowser -delphi

Tags: delphi

I would like to change the line-height of the selected text `TWebbrowser`, but it does not work.

The following code works for changing the font size:

```
(WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).execCommand('fontsize', False, 1);
```

Using the below code to change the line height fails however:

```
(WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).execCommand('lineheight', False, 1);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Please edit your question to be more readable

Comment: Lineheight is a command [that does not exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: @whosrdaddy,thanks for to improve my question.This question is my first one in stack overflow. i will follow the simple and plain procedure .thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no command-constant that can be used to change the line-height the way you are trying to do it (See [Command Identifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533049(v=vs.85).aspx))

Though a bit clumsy, you could do:

```
var
  Selection: IHTMLSelectionObject;
  Range :    IHTMLTxtRange;

begin
  Selection := (WebBrowser1.Document as IHTMLDocument2).Selection;
  if Assigned( Selection ) then
  begin
    Range := Selection.CreateRange as IHTMLTxtRange;
    Range.PasteHTML( '<span style="line-height:100px">' + Range.Text + '</span>' );
  end;
end;
```

Comment: thanks  for the code.i have tried it.and  show the error  message: E2010 Incompatible types: 'IHTMLTxtRange' and 'IDispatch'. Do i miss something ?

Comment: Sorry - I forgot to include the cast after CreateRange

Comment: hi,Mads sorry to post this .  i have tried a lot of time to set the selection area be focus(backgroud color is black)after  the range changing.but it can't work.Can you give any comment?  thanks .

Comment: Not quite following what you are trying to do. Are you trying to give focus back to the WebBrowser if the Range changes programmatically? Maybe write your question as a use-case: "When user does this, system should respond by doing that" and then explain what code you wrote in order to try to make that happen. You could post a brand new question on SO and I will look out for it. Gives you a chance to show what code you've attempted.